# Can we have group header for two apex:columns while using pageblock table?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce-id, dynamic-visualforce, community

My requirement is to get a common header for two apex:columns. I am iterating over pageblocktable.

I know i can use apex:facet for individual apex:column but i dont what to repeat the same header for two columns.

Is there any way that i can achieve this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on common header ? Do you want the same names for both the columns or do you want to show two field values under the same header?

Comment: I want to show two fields values (rather two columns) under same header.

Comment: do you have some code for it?

Comment: Not possible with a standard visualforce.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to "pack" two values into the one `apex:column` into the html table with two columns:

```
<style>
.tbl {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.tbl td {
    width: 50%;
    border: none !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>

<apex:pageBlock title="Block title">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a" >
        <apex:column headerValue="My header">
             <table class="tbl"><tr><td>
             <apex:outputField value="{!a.Name}" /></td><td>
             <apex:outputField value="{!a.CustomerPriority__c}" />
             </td></tr></table>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!a.Id}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with my visualforce page. So I simply added 2 outputFields inside a apex:Column and It works...!

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CampaignMemberList}" var="Cml" >
    <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!Cml.Name}"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!Cml.Status}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!Cml.Attendence__c}"/> 
    <apex:column headerValue="Email" >
    <apex:outputField value="{!Cml.Contact.Email}" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!Cml.Lead.Email}" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```